# Weird casting from string element

Tags: c++, stdstring

I get std:string which should include bytes (array of chars), I'm trying to display the bytes, but first byte always include weird data:

4294967169, how this can be a byte/char?!

```
void do_log(const std::string & data) {
std::stringstream ss;

ss<< "do_log: ";

int min = min((data.length()), (20)); // first 20 bytes

for (int i=0;i<min;i++)
{ 
    ss  << setfill ('0') << setw(2) << hex << (unsigned int)data.at(i) <<" ";
}

log(ss.str());
}
```

Data I log is:
ffffff81 0a 53 3a 30 30 38 31 30 36 43 38

Why and how this ffffff81  appear? if the string.at should return char?

Comment: `char` doesn't have to be unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `(unsigned int)data.at(i)`,  `data.at(i)` is a `char` which then is submitted to integer promotion.  If on your system char is signed, the values greater than 127 are interpreted as negative number. The sign bit will remain in the integer promotion, giving  such strange results.

You can verify if char is signed by looking at [`numeric_limits<char>::is_signed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/?kw=numeric_limits)

You can easily solve the issue by getting rid of the bits added by the integer promotion, by ANDing the integer with 0xff:  `(static_cast<int>(data.at(i)) & 0xff)`

Another way is to force your compiler to work with unsigned chars.  For example, with option `-funsigned-char` on gcc or `/J` with MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

`string` contains signed characters.
So a character 0x81 is interpreted as a negative number, like 0xFFFFFF81.
You cast this character to an unsigned int, so it becomes a very large number.

Comment: You can avoid this by casting your `char` to an `unsigned char` and then casting that to `unsigned int`.

Comment: Isn't it implementation-defined whether `char` is signed?

Comment: No.  `string` is defined as `typedef basic_string<char> string;`.  You would have to declare `basic_string<unsigned char>` if you want a string of unsigned chars.

Comment: It is implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned. `char` is not guaranteed to be `signed char`.

Comment: The string includes bytes of data, so all I need is the first byte (LSB) of the integer, its not my code, and have to use int to send to other function (not mine as well), so this:(static_cast<int>(data.at(i)) & 0xff), work perfect as long as there is no data format change: little endian/big endian